# Extremely strange ClickOnce Web deployment behavior (caching)

Tags: c#, winforms, apache, .net-4.0, clickonce

so I recently deployed my application via ClickOnce to a web server (WAMP to be exact), and had VS2010 auto-generate the webpage and all that jazz.  The users were able to download the application just fine.

The strangeness began when I pushed out my first update.  2 different scenarios occurred.  When then when to website and hit install, it always installed the first version and not the update.  Also, I have a "Check for Updates" Button in the app itself and when they'd click on that it would say "No update available" (using a variation of [this code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404263.aspx)).

On a hunch I had them clear their browser cache and try the "Check for Updates" button in-app again... and lo and behold it worked.

What's going on here? Is it caching the webpage and thus not seeing the updates?  When they visit it the text on the webpage has been updated saying it's the new version but they cannot install until they clear the cache.  Furthermore, is that check for update code hitting the webpage too (How else would that not work either)?  Would placing a NO-CACHE HTML line in the auto-generated webpage's header fix this?  Any suggestions/insights are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd look into how your Apache is set up for caching, like you said. Look into what headers it's sending out. Make sure that it's sending out the .application file with the correct MIME type `application/x-ms-application`

After the ClickOnce is installed, it will always get the same Uri `example.com/app/app.application` and compare the installed version number with the one it just downloaded. When you Publish through Visual Studio it overwrites the file at that location. So, yes, I could see it being a caching issue. It's odd to me that the ApplicationDeployment API would be using the same browser cache, but who knows maybe it uses IE internally.

I have my testing ClickOnce application written on top of MSDN's [asynchronous example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.checkforupdateasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). There's a progress string where you can see it downloading the .application each run. I haven't seen the same issue as you hosting the deployments either on a UNC path or on AWS S3 with static web hosting enabled. That's why I think it may be something in Apache?